# decorative two-colored border (css)

Tags: css, border

Do you have any ideas how I could make this type of two-colored border?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TVVj.png)

I tried with :after, :before, also with width /2 but I think that I did something wrong. Maybe you can help me, Thank you!